# Avoiding object allocations in onDraw() (StaticLayout)?

Tags: android, ondraw

I have a custom view which I quickly learned to not do object allocations in and moved all my Paint allocations into a different method, fine.

I need to use a StaticLayout however for some text that had some spannable 'stuff' applied.

```
    layoutBpm = new StaticLayout(bpmValue,
            textPaintBPM, arcRadius, Layout.Alignment.ALIGN_NORMAL, 0, 1,
            false);

    layoutBpm.draw(canvas);
```

This seemed to make sense to me to have in onDraw but I am of course getting warned to avoid this.  It is important to me that I do everything I can to avoid any performance issues so I am trying to do this properly.

I can't seem to find any documentation I can understand that explains what some of the parameters to StaticLayout actually do (float spacingmult? float spacingadd?), but the third one there I think is maximum width for the StaticLayout text which I can only get from onMeasure as it relates to my canvas size.  This leaves me wanting to put the assignment in onMeasure or onDraw, neither of which it seems I am meant to do.  Is it okay to put StaticLayout assignment in onDraw or is there a better way to do this?

Hope this makes sense, I am very new to this.  Thank you for any help.

(edit: I assume putting this assignment in a method and calling from onDraw/onMeasure is just being silly and will stop Eclipse warning me but wont actually help?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason for the warning is because, very often, you do not need to recreate an object multiple times in a draw operation. `onDraw()` could be called hundreds of times compared to other methods in a `View`.  Most of the time, the objects being recreated are being recreated with the exact parameters.  Other times, it's simply less overhead to change an object's state than it is to create a new object.

In the case of a `StaticLayout`, you only need to create a new one when the text changes or when you adjust the padding, spacing, or maxwidth.  If the text changes often, then you may want to consider `DynamicLayout` which will remeasure itself every time. Remeasuring costs more overhead than creating a new object, but there's no way it's happening more often than `onDraw()` calls.

If the text doesn't change often and you absolutely MUST use a StaticLayout, then you can get away with something like this structure.

```
StaticLayout myLayout;
String textSource = defaultSource;
Paint textPaint = defaultPaint;
int textWidth = defaultWidth; 

public CustomView(Context ctx) {
    super(ctx);
    createLayout();
}

public void setText(String text) {
   textSource = text;
   createLayout();
}

public void setWidth(int width) {
   textWidth = width;
   createLayout();
}

@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
   myLayout.draw(canvas);
}

private void createLayout() {
   myLayout = new StaticLayout(textSource, textPaint, textWidth, Layout.Alignment.ALIGN_NORMAL, 0, 1, false);
}
```

Basically, you only create a new layout when something changes.  Else you just reuse the last object you created.

`EDIT:`

One way to skip a measure pass is to call `View#measure` on the newly resized view itself.  So your `createLayout()` method would be something like this.

```
   private void createLayout() {
       myLayout = new StaticLayout(textSource, textPaint, textWidth, Layout.Alignment.ALIGN_NORMAL, 0, 1, false);
       int textWidthSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(maxLayoutWidth, MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
       int textHeightSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(maxLayoutHeight, MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
       myLayout.measure(textWidthSpec, textHeightSpec);
       forceLayout();
    }
```

Basically what this does is tells the layout the maximum the View can be.  It will measure itself and it's children.  The forceLayout() will be invoked on the parent (your custom view) which will re-layout the other contents based on the new measurements.

I should note that I have never done this with a StaticLayout so I have no idea what will happen.  It seems like this type of measurement might already be handled when the View is created, but maybe not.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, this gave me a slightly new way to look at things.  The only issue I am having implementing the above is that the `textPaint` relies on `onMeasure()` already being called (the text is scaled according to canvas size) and so does the `textWidth` (which determines when the text will wrap), so I can't do `createLayout()` in the constructor for the first viewing.  I can put it in `onMeasure()` which I figure is not called so often though?

Comment: The text actually changes a LOT, the view I am working on is actually a circular SeekBar I have made and the StaticLayout is used for text in the middle which relates to the progress of the SeekBar.  As such when you drag your finger around the circle the value changes constantly.  I thought although the value changes a lot the length is always padded to three digits so the layout would never need to adjust in size and so StaticLayout would be ok.  I can find so little documentation on Static/Dynamic Layouts so I'm not sure if this is correct. Any help again appreciated.

Comment: So finally (I think), I ended up replacing `onMeasure()` with `onSizeChanged()` as my layout needs are simple and putting the initial call to `createLayout()` in there instead of `onMeasure()`.  Lint seems to not mind object allocation in `onSizeChanged()` for some reason but dislikes it in `onMeasure()`.  I would imagine both these methods are called the same amount of times so no idea why it's fine in one and not the other, but whatever, it seems okay.  My main concern was getting allocation out of `onDraw()` which I have done. Thanks again.

Comment: I'm glad you managed to get something working, but here's some notes.

Lint warnings were programmed as simple common mistakes.  Just because you don't get the warning doesn't mean it's good. On the flip side, just because you get a warning doesn't means it's bad. It's no more than a suggestion.

onSizeChanged() doesn't actually get called as much because it will only get called when a *different measurement* was recorded in onMeasure().  onMeasure on the other hand gets called for every View in the tree and possibly even more.  Whether the size changes or not.

Comment: It *is* possible to remeasure a Layout without going through onMeasure() pass.  Basically, with the new measurements, you call `View#measure()` on the view and the view itself will remeasure.  The difference however is the other elements in your parent view will stay the same.  If that's a problem, then you need to invoke a Layout pass to readjust the other elements in the view.  I've update the answer with what I mean.